# Passing an array from Controller to View using Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass an array from my controller to my view using my Model. My method does not work for some reason. I've posted it below.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Confirmation()
    {
        string[] Array = new string[2] {"Pending", "07/07/2013"};
        ConfirmationModel Con = new ConfirmationModel
        {
            Status = Array[0],
            AppDate = Array[1],

        };
        return View();
    }
```

Model:

```
public class ConfirmationModel
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string AppDate { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model site.ConfirmationModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirmation";
}

@Html.DisplayFor(Mode => Model.Status)
@Html.DisplayFor(Mode => Model.AppDate)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't passing your model to your view. Change the line below:

```
return View();
```

To this;

```
return View(Con);
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't actually included the model in the result.  Do this:

```
return View(Con);
```

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You should return populated model to your view. In your case:

```
return view(con)
```

Then use *con* in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any model to the view to be rendered.

The `View()` method has an overload to receive an object model to render in the view.

Try this: `return View(Con);`